# How to sort filenames with dates in ascending order in Python?

Tags: python, file, sorting, filenames

I have a program that walks through a "Data" folder in the project directory and grabs all of the data filenames. The program grabs the path of each file, converts it to a string, and then adds it to a list. the list comes out looking something like this:

```
['./Data/2022\\8\\1\\h00.json', './Data/2022\\8\\1\\h00.rpb', './Data/2022\\8\\1\\h01.json', 
'./Data/2022\\8\\1\\h01.rpb', './Data/2022\\8\\1\\h010.json', './Data/2022\\8\\1\\h010.rpb', 
'./Data/2022\\8\\1\\h011.json', .....]
```

I then have a line to remove the files ending in .rpb so that it just leaves the json files (this is probably a dumb way to do it but I was too lazy to come up with another way). The filenames list then looks like this:

```
['./Data/2022\\8\\1\\h00.json', './Data/2022\\8\\1\\h01.json', './Data/2022\\8\\1\\h010.json', 
'./Data/2022\\8\\1\\h011.json', './Data/2022\\8\\1\\h012.json', .....]
```

The issue here is that I need them to be in ascending date order. That is, I want it to look like this:

```
['./Data/2022\\8\\1\\h00.json', './Data/2022\\8\\1\\h01.json', './Data/2022\\8\\1\\h02.json', 
'./Data/2022\\8\\1\\h03.json', './Data/2022\\8\\1\\h04.json',
...
'./Data/2022\\8\\1\\h021.json', './Data/2022\\8\\1\\h022.json', 
'./Data/2022\\8\\1\\h023.json', './Data/2022\\8\\2\\h00.json', './Data/2022\\8\\2\\h01.json', 
'./Data/2022\\8\\2\\h02.json', ....]
```

The format for the filenames are a date and time, so that's year, month, day, hour.

Below is the part of my program that is grabbing the filenames. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

```
import json
import csv
import sys
import os
from os import walk
from os import path

import datetime as datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import re

from _datetime import datetime


if __name__ == "__main__":


    # begin looking for files #
    mypath = "./Data/"

    # START DEBUGGING WALK #
    # print(filenames)
    # print("\n")
    filenames = []
    for root, dirs, files in walk(mypath):
        for name in files:
            print(name)
            print(path.join(root, name))
            # filenames.append(name)
            filenames.append(path.join(root, name))
    print("filenames\n")
    print(filenames)
    if filenames[0] == './Data/output.csv':
        filenames = filenames[1::2]
    else:
        filenames = filenames[0::2]
    print("no rpb")
    print(filenames)
```

Comment: If you have control over how the file names are generated, I´d suggest zero-padding all the fields. That way, you can just sort them alphabetically.

Comment: @MagnusReftel That's a great idea. I will try to do this. Thank you!